# error in event viewer

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

I have two question....

when i drop some Edi file in receive location......if there is some error in file.....we get some error in event viewer(I guesss these are receive pipeline error).....

my first question is

```
           can we se this error in the sql server .................In which database and table we can see event viewer error.
```

My second question is

```
          can we get this error and write into some file through biztalk.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first question is

```
           can we se this error in the sql server .................In which database and table we can see event viewer error. --> I guess No.
```

My second question is

```
          can we get this error and write into some file through biztalk. --> Yes you can do that. following are few ways
```

1.Use Enterprise Library logging and catch the error in pipeline if you are using custom pipeline and write those errors in flat file
2.if you use SCOM , it will automatically poll all the errors related with BizTalk in event viewer and sends notifications to you.
3.Write a custom service using .net and read the event logs on each bizTalk nodes, later you can either write them in flat file or push them in database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578516.aspx.  You could route the message to a file and or SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on BAM and EDI reporting there will be a nicer view in the admin console.